# .read_csv() in pandas isn't reading escape characters properly

Tags: python, pandas, csv, etl

I'm trying to create an ETL pipeline with pandas and CSVing the data but I'm having some problems with some escape characters.

If, for example, my data is '\"' and the escapechar defined is '\' with quotechar '"', when I read the file my data turns into "\", missing one escapechar.

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3: 
    from StringIO import StringIO
else:
    from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd
import csv

escape_char_defined = '\\'
quote_defined = '"'
separator = "|"

sample_data = []

for i in range(1,11):
    sample_data.append(i*escape_char_defined + quote_defined)

initial_df = pd.DataFrame(sample_data,columns=['column'])


csv_text = initial_df.to_csv(sep=separator,columns=None,header=None,index=False,doublequote=False,quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL,quotechar=quote_defined,escapechar=escape_char_defined,encoding='utf-8')

csv_text = StringIO(csv_text)

final_df = pd.read_csv(csv_text,sep=separator,escapechar=escape_char_defined,quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL,header=None,doublequote=False,encoding='utf-8')

if not final_df.equals(initial_df):
    raise Exception("Dataframes are not equal!")
```

I don't think this is an expected behaviour since I'm using the same tools to write and read the CSV text.

Does anyone already have a problem with this ?

Comment: Have you tried to set the encoding? `pd.read_csv(your_parameters, encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: @CarloZanocco, yes but the result is the same. I'll update the code snippet to cover this.

Comment: Well, what is desirable is having the same Dataframe as I defined. If I a field like **\"**, the expected load from a CSV file is the same string.

Yes, I've tried to set other **escapechar** but pandas only allows me using one character to escape :

**"escapechar" must be a 1-character string**

Answer (score 2):

Here the fixed code if I correctly understood what you need.

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3: 
    from StringIO import StringIO
else:
    from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd
import csv

escape_char_defined = "\\"
quote_defined = '"'
separator = "|"

sample_data = []

for i in range(1,11):
    sample_data.append(i*escape_char_defined + quote_defined)

initial_df = pd.DataFrame(sample_data,columns=['column'])

csv_text = initial_df.to_csv(sep=separator,columns=None,quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE,header=None,index=False,doublequote=False,quotechar=quote_defined,escapechar=escape_char_defined)
csv_text = StringIO(csv_text)
final_df = pd.read_csv(csv_text,names=(["column"]),sep=separator,quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE,escapechar=escape_char_defined,quotechar=quote_defined,header=None,doublequote=False)

if not final_df.equals(initial_df):
    raise Exception("Dataframes are not equal!")
```

I have replaced the `quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL` in the `pd.to_csv()` and `pd.read_csv()` with `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE`.

The option `csv.QUOTE_NONE` block the writer to quote fields. 
If the current delimiter is present in the output data is preceded by the current escapechar. 
If it isn't set the writer will raise an error if any characters that require escaping are encountered.

In the pd.read_csv() I have also added the column name as `'column'`

Comment: That's a way to solve it but I need to have my fields delimited by quotes.

Comment: I'm thinking, I'll edit the post if I find a solution